# Fixed bg imgae jumps on mobile scolling how to fix?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a webpage with a background image that remains fixed while scrolling the content. Below is my HTML and CSS code for achieving this effect. However, I'm encountering issues with the proper display of the background image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uz">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ansormed - Bosh sahifa</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css"> -->
  
  <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body-bg">
  </div>
<!-- Content --\>
</body\>
</html\>
```

```
body{
  position: relative;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: var(--text-font);
  background-color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.body-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('../img/doctor-bg-img.jpeg') #555 no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```